# Moodle php_extension intl

Tags: apache, moodle

After installing Moodle 3.7.2 on Ubuntu with Apache it gives me a warning that the php intl extension needs to be installed and enabled.
I installed the extension by apt-get install php-intl, restarted apache, but Moodle still says its not installed or enabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out apache was running with php7.2 instead of7.3 where installed the extension in.
After switching to php7.3 it all worked out.